# Is this definition of "static" variables incorrect, misleading, or neither?

Tags: c, scope, static, lifetime

According to https://www.learn-c.org/en/Static:

> By default, variables are local to the scope in which they are defined. **Variables can be declared as static to increase their scope up to file containing them**. As a result, **these variables can be accessed anywhere inside a file.**

Two code examples are provided.
First, an example where local variable `int count` is removed from memory after the function `runner()` returns:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int runner() {
    int count = 0;
    count++;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d ", runner());
    printf("%d ", runner());
    return 0;
}
```

The output is: `1 1`.

The next example given makes `count` static:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int runner()
{
    static int count = 0;
    count++;
    return count;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d ", runner());
    printf("%d ", runner());
    return 0;
}
```

The output this time is: `1 2`.

`count` increased to 2 in this example because it wasn't removed from memory at the return of `runner()`.
...BUT, that doesn't seem to relate to the statement at the beginning of the page about static variables being accessed anywhere inside a file. The two examples only show that `static` allowed `count` to remain in memory across multiple calls to `runner()` (and that it is not set to 0 each call). They do not show whether or not `count` can be accessed "*anywhere inside a file*", because `main()` simply prints whatever `runner()` returns.

To illustrate my point, I made an example showing that `static` does not make `count()` accessible anywhere inside a file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void runner()
{
    static int count = 0;
    count++;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    runner();
    printf("%d ", count);
    runner();
    printf("%d ", count);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:12:23: error: 'count' undeclared (first use in this function)
         printf("%d ", count);
                       ^
prog.c:12:23: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

That is what I expected.

I made another example, this one uses `x` which can be accessed by both `runner()` and `main()`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int x = 0;
void runner()
{
    static int count = 0;
    count++;
    x = count;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    runner();
    printf("%d ", x);
    runner();
    printf("%d ", x);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is: `1 2`.

Is the quote at the top of this question incorrect, misleading, or neither? Am I misunderstanding a semantics issue?

Comment: I think the author is confusing scope with storage duration (and linkage), and has a very peculiar view of what accessing a variable is. AFAIK, there are no good online C tutorials, at least none that are easy to find.

Comment: Time to abandon the site. It is giving you misinformation.  That is a serious problem in a teaching website.

Comment: It's good that you post these kind of things on SO so we can shame those sites in public. I still think SO needs a "black list" or something...

Comment: @Lundin : maybe there should be a section in the C tag wiki on black-listed sites, maybe with a link to an example of why it is black-listed.  Or maybe that’s not something SO could/should do. Tempting, though.

Comment: I've been trying to find a website for my buddy who's completely new to code in general. I wanted to give them a way to learn with interactive examples, since they are so new that they get overwhelmed looking at an IDE. Thus I found learn-c.org and thought it would be helpful, but I have found numerous issues with most of the pages there. At first I thought it was my own understanding or verbiage at fault, but I now see that indeed, the author doesn't know what they're talking about, *and* is bad at showing through examples. How can someone make a tutorial and be so wrong!?

Comment: Yes it is a sad state of affairs. Worse yet, many C books are also crap - and those which aren't, are often too advanced for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** - A variable with static storage *lives* throughout the entire execution of the program and any access made to it would be valid. Whether it *can be accessed* from any part or not, depends on the *scope* of the definition.

So, to answer the title: I'd agree, it's misleading but at the same time, I'll add a little more context to elaborate on the actual message that was attempted to be communicated.

---

You already had your answer, just to add my two cents (using authoritative words from the standard):

`static` is a storage class specifier, it helps determining the storage duration.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.4

> An object has a *storage duration* that determines its **lifetime**. [....]

Then,

> The **lifetime** of an object is the portion of program execution during which storage is
>   guaranteed to be reserved for it. An object exists, has a constant address,<sup>33)</sup> and retains
>   its last-stored value throughout its lifetime. [...]

So, for variables with *static storage duration*,

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
>   `_Thread_local`, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

---

***'nuff talk, show me teh codez:***

So, to compare, let's see the snippets:

- Snippet one: **Invalid Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
char *func()
{
    char arr [ ] = "Hello!";
    return arr;
}

int main()
{        
    printf("%s ", func()); // you're accessing `arr`, some or other way!!
    return 0;
}
```

Here, the returned pointer points to invalid memory, as with the end of the function call, the automatic local variable `arr` is destroyed (lifetime expired), and the returned address points to invalid memory now.

So, even if you have a way to access `arr`, that access is not valid anymore.

- Snippet 2: **valid Code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
char *func()
{
    static char arr [ ] = "Hello!";
    return arr;
}

int main()
{        
    printf("%s ", func()); // you're accessing `arr`, some or other way!!
    return 0;
}
```

this is a perfectly valid code, as it makes `arr` "accessible" outside the scope of it's definition, because of the *static storage duration*.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, and the quote is wrong.  Declaring a variable in a function block `static` increases its lifetime, not its scope.  (Scope is the portion of code where you can use a name.)

I can't really imagine a correct way of interpreting "accessed anywhere inside a file".  If you have a pointer to a variable of this sort, it's valid to dereference that pointer in other functions, but that's true of all functions, not just the ones in the same file.

Probably time to stop using that site.

Comment: "accessed anywhere inside a file" sounds like the author is confusing one of the other definitions of "static".  At file scope, "static" gives a variable internal linkage so it can *only* be accessed from within the translation unit that defines it.

Comment: @WilliamPursell explains the problem the original author seems to have had. Or the lines they're blurring over.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yet `static` on a function **reduces** the scope of its visibility, instead of **increasing** is as the quote claims. This alone should be enough to dismiss the quote as plain wrong without second thought. Obviously, the author of the quote was mixing something up, but as far as I am concerned, it does not really matter *how* they actually messed up: The result is, that the quote just points in the opposite direction of the truth.

Comment: @cmaster I thought the quote was meant for static _variables_ ?

Comment: @SouravGhosh You can put static variables at file scope, and it will reduce their scope just the same as for functions. If you put such a static variable into a header, each including `.c` file will have it's own copy of that file-scope variable.

Answer (score 2):

That tutorial is wildly confused and needs to be deleted from the Internet.

---

C has two different, but related terms: *scope* and *storage duration*. Scope specifies where a variable can be accessed through its name. Storage duration specifies for how long a variable will retain its value.

In your 2 first examples, you do not change the scope of the variable at all, you change its storage duration.

The scope remains the very same: the variable has local scope to the function `int runner()` and cannot be accessed by its name outside that function. The keyword `static` does not affect scope.

However, you change the storage duration. All `static` variables have (unsurprisingly) *static storage duration*, which means they will keep their contents valid throughout the whole execution of the program. This is why the function remembers the value when called a second time.

And finally, to address further misconceptions of the tutorial, there is another term called *linkage*, which is also related to scope. Variables with *internal linkage* are definitely just accessible in the .c file where they are declared (and in all included .h files from that .c file).

Whereas variables with *external linkage* are explicitly accessible all over the program, using the keyword `extern`. You cannot combine internal and external linkage - and all variables declared as `static` will get internal linkage. Meaning you won't be able to access them from other .c files.

By declaring a variable `static`, you give it static storage duration and internal linkage.

Functions follow the same rules for scope and linkage as variables, except storage duration isn't meaningful to functions.

Comment: >You cannot combine internal and external linkage - and all variables declared as static will get internal linkage. Meaning you won't be able to access them from other .c files.< While true, I think it might mystify the OP. The point is that >static< creates quite different behaviours that seem contradictory. As long as within a function scope, it only seems to change lifetime. But if used outside any function, if actually limits scope through linkage, meaning that you cannot access the variable outside its translation unit. Although it is about linkage, the effect is more scope-like.

Answer (score 1):

The quote is confusing *scope* and *lifetime*.

The **scope** of a variable describes where a variable can be accessed *by name*.  The **lifetime** of a variable, or more accurately an *object*, describes when the object is valid.  For a non-static local variable, both its scope and its lifetime is the block it is defined in.

In the case of a `static` as in your example, its scope is still the enclosing block but its lifetime is that of the whole program.  This means you can return the address of a `static` variable and dereferencing that address is valid.  For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *runner()
{
    static int count = 0;
    count++;
    return &count;    // ok, count has full program lifetime
}

int main()
{
    int *p = runner();
    printf("%d ", *p);
    p = runner();
    printf("%d ", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2
```

If you however attempt to do this with a non-static variable:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *runner()
{
    int count = 0;
    count++;
    return &count;    // BAD: count no longer exists when function returns
}

int main()
{
    int *p = runner();
    printf("%d ", *p);   // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
    p = runner();
    printf("%d ", *p);   // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR
    return 0;
}
```

You invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by using a pointer to an object that no longer exists.